Multiplication Well Defined Under Integers
I am trying to prove that multiplication is well-defined for integers represented as equivalence classes of ordered pairs of integers. (I'm aware there are other threads on this, as mentioned at the bottom, but honestly, after thinking about it all day, I'm still a bit stuck). Help greatly appreciated!
Equivalence Relation
The equivalence relation on the integers is defined as: $(A, B) \sim (\tilde{A}, \tilde{B}) \iff A + \tilde{B} = B + \tilde{A}$. For example, $(3, 1) \sim (4, 2)$ because $3 + 2 = 1 + 4$.
1. Setup
The multiplication of two equivalence classes is defined as: $[(A,B)]⋅[(C,D)]=[(AC+BD,AD+BC)]$.
Given two equivalence classes:
(1) $(A, B) \sim (\tilde{A}, \tilde{B}) \implies A + \tilde{B} = B + \tilde{A}$
(2) $(C, D) \sim (\tilde{C}, \tilde{D}) \implies C + \tilde{D} = D + \tilde{C}$.
I need to show that: $[(A, B)] \cdot [(C, D)] = [(\tilde{A}, \tilde{B})] \cdot [(\tilde{C}, \tilde{D})]$
I.e. $(AC + BD, AD + BC) \sim (\tilde{A}\tilde{C} + \tilde{B}\tilde{D}, \tilde{A}\tilde{D} + \tilde{B}\tilde{C})$.
which gives us the following through our equivalence relation:
$(AC + BD + \tilde{A}\tilde{D} + \tilde{B}\tilde{C}) = (AD + BC + \tilde{A}\tilde{C} + \tilde{B}\tilde{D})$
2. Multiply our origional Equivalences & Substitute
Start with the equivalences: $(A + \tilde{B})(C + \tilde{D}) = (B + \tilde{A})(D + \tilde{C})$.
Use $(2)$ : $(A + \tilde{B})(C + \tilde{D}) = (B + \tilde{A})(C + \tilde{D})$
LHS: $(A + \tilde{B})(C + \tilde{D}) = AC + A\tilde{D} + \tilde{B}C + \tilde{B}\tilde{D}$
RHS: $(B + \tilde{A})(C + \tilde{D}) = BC + B\tilde{D} + \tilde{A}C + \tilde{A}\tilde{D}$.
3. Group Terms
LHS: $(AC + \tilde{B}\tilde{D}) + (A\tilde{D} + \tilde{B}C)$.
RHS $(B\tilde{D} + \tilde{A}C) + (BC + \tilde{A}\tilde{D})$.
$(AC + \tilde{B}\tilde{D}, BC + \tilde{A}\tilde{D}) \sim  (A\tilde{D} + \tilde{B}C, B\tilde{D} + \tilde{A}C)$
Which looks productive as if I was separating out the cross terms. But doesn't feel like it's going anywhere after this! I was hoping I could use it to define equivalence with cross terms on the right and matching terms on the left. But i feel like to do this i would need to reverse use the multiplication property we are trying to prove, which seems invalid.
4. Multiplying Equivalences by C
I also attempted to multiply the equivalence relation $A + \tilde{B} = B + \tilde{A}$ by $C$, which gives: $AC + \tilde{B}C = BC + \tilde{A}C$, and substitute this into the terms, but i can't see it adding anything.
Where I'm Stuck
I I think part of the problem is, I'm not sure what I'm allowed to do.

I'm assuming that given the pre-requisite this was defining the Natural Numbers and their operations, we are allowed to multiply our two different representations i.e. Given two equivalence classes:
$(A, B)(C, D) \sim (\tilde{A}, \tilde{B})(\tilde{C}, \tilde{D}) \implies (A + \tilde{B})(C + \tilde{D}) = (B + \tilde{A})(D + \tilde{C})$

I have seen some proofs, where they multiplier something like the above as I have done but then  they also add another four terms on the LHS and RHS. I think this might allow them to rearrange and then cancel getting us to our desired equality, but it's not obvious to me if/why we are allowed to cancel terms.


I have looked at a number of other threads on Maths Stack (1) (2), but I find each of them confusing, partly because the answers seem to come dispersed in comments and some of which are claiming that it hasn't been done right. If anyone would be willing to spell it out that'd be so appreciated!

It might be helpful to recognize that the equivalence relation essentially expresses subtraction. What you want to show is that $(A-B)(C-D) = (\bar{A} - \bar{B} ) ( \bar{C} - \bar {D})$. You likely want to use the intermediate step of $ = (A-B)( \bar{C} - \bar {D}) = $ (Which means that for step 4, instead of only multiplying by $C$, we multiply by $\bar{C} - \bar{D}$). Hope this helps.

Thanks for your comment Calvin! I believe I understand that (A,B) for example is meant to represent A-B, but because we don't have subtraction defined, we have to use the addition walk around when defining our equivalence relation. How could I do something like what you suggested without introducing any actual subtraction? ideally i'd like to avoid this.

The general trick is to write out what you want with subtraction, then "fix" every equation used by moving negated terms to the opposite side, and by some miracle all those "fixed" equations turn out to be justified by the definition of equivalence. People either find this to be proof that the whole formalism is silly or validation that we've set up the formalism correctly.

Hi @Calvin, thank you so much for your comments. I will digest and see if I can get it to work!

@CormJack I deleted my recent comments as it doesn't make sense to treat an equivalence class as a scalar (though there's a very natural interpretation). Instead, I've shown how to manipulate it.

Observation: Verify the following :

We can multiply throughout by a scalar, namely $(kA, kB) \sim (k\bar{A} , k\bar{B})$.
We can swap coordinates, namely $(B, A) \sim (\bar{B}, \bar{A})$.
We can add equivalence classes coordinate-wise, namely $(A+C, B+D) \sim ( \bar{A} + \bar{C} , \bar{B} + \bar{D})$.

Lemma: $( A, B) \cdot (C, D) \sim (\bar{A} , \bar{B}) \cdot (C, D)$.
We want to show that $(AC + BD, AD + BC) \sim (\bar{A}C + \bar{B}D, \bar{A}D + \bar{B}C)$. This follows from adding up:

$(AC, BC) \sim (\bar{A} C, \bar{B} C )$: True by multiplying by $C$.
$(BD, AD ) \sim ( \bar{B} D, \bar{A} D)$: True by swapping coordinates then multiplying by $D$.

Corollary: Applying the Lemma twice appropriately,
$$( A, B) \cdot (C, D) \sim (\bar{A} , \bar{B}) \cdot (C, D) \sim (\bar{A}, \bar{B} ) \cdot ( \bar{C} , \bar{D}).$$
